# Usar controle de versão no servidor de produção é uma boa prática?

Tags: c#, team-foundation-server, versionamento

Na empresa em que trabalho atualmente, temos um sistema Web (C# ASP.NET) onde usamos no ambiente de desenvolvimento o Team Foundation Server 2013. No servidor de produção não usamos nenhum controle de versão: usamos somente FTP, mas hoje surgiu um debate aqui de como sabemos quem colocou um código no ambiente de produção ou quem modificou.

Gostaria de saber se colocar controle de versão no servidor de produção é uma boa prática e com um só repositório que contenha o ambiente de produção e desenvolvimento.

**Atualização**

O meu objetivo é: quando eu subir alguma modificação para o servidor, que não seja via FTP, mas via controle de versão para que haja histórico das modificações realizadas no **ambiente de produção**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como o Luiz Vieira bem colocou, você já tem histórico e controle de versão, no seu ambiente de produção você não está rodando código, está rodando binários.

**O TFS deve ser único, o seu controle de versão deve ser único.**

O que você tem que se preocupar é o que está rodando em cada ambiente e você faz isso a partir do *build*. É no *build* que você vai amarrar a versão do binário, que vai te levar as alterações no código, aos seus requisitos, etc.

E para promover o *build* entre ambientes hoje a Microsoft tem uma solução de automação de deploy chamada [Release Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/release-management-vs.aspx). Como ela você promove os binários e terá um histórico do que está rodando no ambiente.

Comment: Brandão, entendi é isso mesmo que precisamos aqui. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Se você quiser fazer perguntas mais específicas, e detalhar o seu ambiente, daí posso detalhar melhor... Por exemplo, me diz qual a linguagem você está usando, plataforma... daí já rolar outros toques...

Answer (score 8):

A minha resposta vai ser dada de forma independente de tecnologia de desenvolvimento.

A sua pergunta essencial é:

> "Como sabemos quem colocou um código no ambiente de produção?"

Idealmente, o sistema em execução no ambiente de produção é uma versão fechada, bem definida e unicamente identificável por meio de (ao menos) um código de versão como "v.1.0.0". Esse tipo de identificação existe essencialmente pra permitir aos administradores saberem exatamente o que está sendo executado no servidor em termos das funcionalidades implementadas.

Se o seu projeto usa um controle de versão da forma correta, o seu processo de trabalho é resumidamente o seguinte:

1. Os desenvolvedores trabalham sobre a correção de problemas e implementação de novidades decorrentes de pedidos específicos, geralmente identificados por números de "tickets" em um sistema de controle de alterações (que pode ou não ser integrado ao sistema de controle de versão). As alterações no código são feitas de forma que sejam rastreáveis em relação a esses pedidos. Por exemplo, ao fazer os commits no Git, os desenvolvedores podem indicar no comentário qual é o número do ticket ao qual as alterações se relacionam.
2. Alguém responsável na equipe planeja a próxima versão (por exemplo, v.1.0.1) em termos de quais correções e novidades vão ser entregues. Essa pessoa cobra os desenvolvedores pela implementação do código e os integradores pelos testes de regressão, e eventualmente demanda a produção (compilação) da nova versão, que incluirá apenas as mudanças planejadas. Isso tudo é feito fora do servidor de produção, até porque pode ser feito enquanto o sistema atual está em execução e servindo aos clientes.
3. Depois da nova versão gerada, ela é atualizada no servidor de produção (em algum momento oportuno, como por exemplo durante a noite em que o uso do sistema é menor e a interrupção para atualização gerará menos transtornos). A partir da identificação da versão (v.1.0.1) e da matriz de rastreabilidade provida pelas ferramentas utilizadas e, principalmente, pelo processo (em que os problemas são descritos por um ticket específico e os desenvolvedores sempre lembram de indicar tais tickets nos comentários dos commits), é fácil identificar quais alterações foram adicionadas (e quem as fez) ao novo sistema em execução no servidor de produção. Ainda mais importante do que isso, em caso de [regressões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9044/estrat%C3%A9gias-para-prevenir-regress%C3%A3o-de-software), é mais fácil identificar a causa.

Em resumo, você só sabe quem colocou algo no servidor de produção se tem o histórico das atualizações efetuadas e as atualizações futuras são feitas de forma independente do que está em execução hoje.

Usar controle de versão no servidor não é um problema em si desde que as áreas com o que é executado e o que está sendo desenvolvido sejam mantidas separadas. Caso contrário, o que está sendo executado (supondo algo que seja interpretado) será constantemente alterado e você simplesmente perde o controle de quais funcionalidades estão em uso. Mas do ponto de vista de desempenho e segurança, não parece ser uma boa ideia usar o mesmo servidor para as duas tarefas. A mesma máquina estará dividindo recursos pra o cliente final e para os desenvolvedores, e qualquer necessidade de parada (para atualizar o seu software de controle de versão, por exemplo) vai impactar na disponibilidade do serviço para os clientes.

Se você não usa nenhum sistema de controle de versão (só FTP, como diz), é ainda mais importante manter as estruturas separadas para você ter *ao menos* algum controle manual de quais as funcionalidades estarão em execução. Em algum momento, alguém responsável vai precisar interromper as atividades de codificação para "agrupar" o código em uma versão identificável e colocá-la no servidor de produção.

Comment: Prezado Luiz, acho que me expressei mal, nós já usamos o sistema de controle de versão no ambiente de desenvolvimento. No ambiente de produção que eu gostaria de usar para que haja histórico/rastreabilidade das modificações subidas para o servidor de produção. Ou se acontece um erro grave em alguma página e é necessária uma correção rápida.

Comment: Bom, eu ainda não entendi. Se você já tem o histórico no ambiente de desenvolvimento, por que você precisa dele duplicado no ambiente de produção? Sobre erros graves em produção, você deveria testar as páginas *antes* de colocá-las em produção justamente para evitar erros e para evitar ter de "atualizar às pressas" (porque dai vc perde mesmo o controle).

Comment: @williamhk2 um ponto da resposta é: não altere código no servidor de produção; todo código alterado só deve chegar à produção através de uma release, que possui um número de versão, e através deste número você rastreia quem fez o que e por que. Subir código diretamente para o servidor de produção é onde está o seu problema e para o qual você não vai encontrar solução boa. Mesmo uma correção rápida não deveria ter motivo para não seguir o caminho correto: subir para o versionador padrão do time, a partir do qual será criado um pacote com número de versão.

Comment: @Caffé é isso mesmo! Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Achei as duas respostas certas, mas a resposta do brandão me fez entender isso que você disse agora.

Comment: Sem erro, não se preocupe. :)