# O que é Teste de Regressão?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, testes

Na matéria de Teste de Software o professor abordou um termo chamado *Teste de Regressão*, isto dentro da disciplina de teste de software. Sendo assim, este termo me gerou algumas dúvidas a respeito de este de software.

## Dúvidas

1. O que seria o Teste de Regressão?
2. Quais os benefícios em se fazer Teste de Regressão?
3. O que é esta "regressão" relacionada ao teste?

Comment: Resumidamente, o Teste de Regressão é uma das principais  [estratégias para se previnir a Regressão de sofware](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13530/4186).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> O que seria o Teste de Regressão?

Identificar erros previamente não existentes após mudanças em código.

> Quais os benefícios em se fazer Teste de Regressão?

Mexer em time que está ganhando e continuar ganhando.

> O que é esta "regressão" relacionada ao teste?

A regressão é justamente algo que funcionava e não funciona mais, é andar para trás, estragar o que estava bom. É um *bug* introduzido por uma mudança posterior no código. Não há regressão no desenvolvimento inicial.

## Explicando

Esse efetivamente é o teste mais importante que tem para fazer formalmente. Sem ele você sempre corre o risco de mudar algo e o que funcionava deixar de funcionar.

Podemos dizer que ele é o oposto do TDD, embora eles não se oponham, digo apenas no sentido que TDD se preocupa com definir o que deve fazer para depois fazer, e o teste de regressão se preocupa em garantir que o que foi feito sempre seja feito assim.

Ele é especialmente útil em bases de código que serão utilizados publicamente e/ou em larga escala.

É comum usarmos testes de unidade para estabelecer testes de regressão. O teste de regressão não é uma técnica específica, é uma metodologia mais ampla que usam ferramentas específicas.

Outro objetivo dele é não deixar que um erro encontrado ocorra novamente. Por isso quando um *bug* é encontrado escreve-se o teste de unidade e ele passa fazer parte do teste de regressão.

O teste de unidade não é a única técnica. Um teste de carga pode ser um teste de regressão. De que adianta tudo funcionar corretamente se a mudança feita trouxe uma perda de performance, escalabilidade, etc.?

Sabe esses sites que avaliam se o seu código produziu o resultado correto e te dá pontos? Pelo menos os mais sofisticados estão fazendo uma espécie de teste de regressão. Tem que dar uma saída específica, no tempo específico, com um consumo específico.

Teste de regressão pode ser totalmente automatizado e nem precisa de acesso especial aos detalhes de implementação.

Ele te dá confiança para mudar o código, seja por uma mudança de requisito, seja por refatoração.

Teste sem um propósito claro não serve para muita coisa. Até o TDD, que eu costumo ser crítico para a maioria dos casos ,mas não todos, tem um propósito claro, ainda que eu discorde que seja tão útil ou que atinjam ele com esta ferramenta. O teste de regressão tem um propósito claro.

Digo isso porque muito dos testes que fazem por aí tem como propósito fazer testes. As pessoas sequer sabem porque estão fazendo, o que elas querem combater, o que resolver, não tem uma metodologia para alcançar resultados. Não digo que seja puro desperdício de tempo, mas poderia ser melhor empregado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Como é bom ver respostas que vem do próprio punho.

Comment: Ver também explicações de como previnir a regressão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13530/4186

Answer (score 0):

**O que seria o Teste de Regressão?**

Imagine que um programa foi projetado e construído com etapas bem definidas, seguindo-se a elas testes de softwares para verificarem possíveis falhas ou incompatibilidades. Tudo estava excelente até que o software recebeu uma pequena atualização. É aqui que o teste de regressão entra. Ele é feito após modificações, atualizações, inclusão de funcionalidades ou correção de defeitos, para checar se as mudanças não causaram algum problema no programa, gerando instabilidade ou erros.

O porém é que ele demanda tempo, podendo ser mais ou menos o mesmo usado antes na hora de executar os testes nas etapas anteriores. Mas ele é extremamente importante, pois uma nova analisada pode ajudar a se identificar falhas que passaram antes. Também é possível usar um software de automação de testes nessa tarefa, embora seja interessante o avaliador tentar checar novamente os componentes o máximo possível.

É possível realizar o teste de regressão novamente em todo o sistema, só na parte modificada ou onde acredita-se que houve alteração por conta da atualização. Partes que tiveram suas funções alteradas por ela.

**Quais os benefícios em se fazer Teste de Regressão?**

O teste de regressão evita que problemas que julgavam-se resolvidos retornem, prejudicando e invalidando quase todos os testes anteriores. É uma espécie de checagem final, para avaliar se tudo está bem mesmo, conforme o que foi planejado, evitando aborrecimentos futuros.

**O que é esta "regressão" relacionada ao teste?**

Bom, a regressão seria como se após inserir uma funcionalidade nova o sistema não fique a merce de algum "bug" pois teste de regressão preza por preparar sistema para este tipo de erro o retornando e identificando o momento em que sistema não foi capaz de reconhecer a nova funcionalidade

Comment: http://wevtimoteo.github.io/o-que-e-teste-de-regressao.html  
testesdesoftware.com/teste-de-regressao

Comment: Resumidamente [o termo "regressão"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9044/estrat%c3%a9gias-para-prevenir-regress%c3%a3o-de-software/13530#comment67522_13530) é utilizado porque os programadores vivenciaram por décadas o fenômeno de ver um certo bug1 *regressando* magicamente depois da correção de um certo bug2. É de fato uma sençação trágica de *dejavu*, por isso o termo faz todo o sentido para quem tem experiência no ramo :-)