# Qual a diferença entre teste de regressão e teste de ponta a ponta

Tags: terminologia, testes, automatização, testes-funcionais, testes-automatizados

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre estes dois testes, teste de regressão e teste de ponta a ponta. Procurei em alguns lugares mas achava material mais relacionado a TDD, e ambos se parecem um pouco.

Quando usar teste de regressão ou um teste de ponta a ponta, ao estar testando um software?

Comment: Ver também explicações de como previnir a regressão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13530/4186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testes de regressão: Todos os testes que serão reexecutados para garantir o funcionamento do software (das funcionalidades existentes e cobertas por testes). Caso alguma funcionalidade tenha o comportamento alterado de forma indesejada, estes testes vão falhar e evidenciar qual parte do sistema foi impactada pelo novo código. Pode ser manual, automatizado, unitário etc.

Testes ponta a ponta: Testes efetuados no sistema integrado. Com ambiente idêntico (ou o mais próximo possível) do usuário final, exercitando os fluxos completos do sistema ou funcionalidade (e não apenas uma pequena parte). Ex: Em um processo de desenvolvimento de uma aplicação web, poderíamos ter diversos níveis de testes: testes unitários, testes de integração, testes no frontend com mocks, testes na api (ou backend) etc. O teste ponta a ponta será feito quando todas as dependências estiverem disponíveis, ou seja, em um ambiente com o frontend, apis, banco de dados conectados, utilizando o mesmo ambiente que o usuário final utilizará.

Recomendo que faça testes ponta a ponta sempre que houver a menor porção entregável possível disponível. Recomendo também que os automatize (aumentando a cobertura dos seus testes de regressão)